# error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class cv::Mat’ & error: forward > declaration of ‘class cv::Mat’ in CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, codeblocks

Need help here... I just left these error from my program code. When I try to build my program, from the *mat.hpp* file keep on pop up the error with class cv::Mat.

> ../../gitRepo/recotraffic2.git/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp|58|error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class cv::Mat’|

```
inline void Mat::initEmpty()
{
    flags = MAGIC_VAL;
    dims = rows = cols = 0;
    data = datastart = dataend = datalimit = 0;
    refcount = 0;
    allocator = 0;
}

inline Mat::Mat() : size(&rows)
{
    initEmpty();
}

inline Mat::Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type) : size(&rows)
{
    initEmpty();
    create(_rows, _cols, _type);
}

inline Mat::Mat(int _rows, int _cols, int _type, const Scalar& _s) : size(&rows)
{
    initEmpty();
    create(_rows, _cols, _type);
    *this = _s;
}
```

then the *base.hpp* also came out the error below from that line:

> /usr/local/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp|627|error: forward
>   declaration of ‘class cv::Mat’|

```
class CV_EXPORTS Mat;
```

Comment: I have same error. did you manage to solve it? I guess it relates to me trying to compile opencv myself...